# Jupyter notebook freezes when try to use "display.max_rows" to show all of the data

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipython, data-analysis

I'm new to python and jupyter notebook.

I loaded a csv file with 7000 rows of data into pandas DataFrame in jupyter notebook. But every time I try to use "pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)", and then "df" to display all of the data in a cell. Jupyter notebook freezes and never shows the results. When I try to do this in command line in Ipython, it will show the results. How do I get it to work in jupyter notebook as well?

python code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\DA\movies.csv\movies.csv')
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
df
```

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/danielgrijalvas/movies

Computer specs: Intel Core i5-10500 (6 cores), 16 GB memory

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I just switched to Chrome browser and it worked. But it won't work in Firefox for some reason.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).